# Como llamar al evento ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Cómo llamar al evento **ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged** desde una función? quiero desencadenar los sucesos que están programados en el *SelectedIndexChanged*.

Comment: Vi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829381/is-it-possible-to-fire-combobox-selectedindex-changed-event-even-when-old-and-ne

Comment: Del enlace que comarte @B.ClayShannon te recomiendo mucho, que utlizes la segunda tecnica, la que no es respuesta aceptada, simpre es mejor

Comment: Gracias por la info, lo aplicare y mas tarde publico el resultado

Answer (score 2):

No se invoca directo al codigo de un evento, no es una buena practica de desarrollo, el código reutilizable lo deberias llevar a una funcion separada

```
public void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, ...)
{
    FuncionalidadComun();
}   

public void button1_Click(..)
{
    FuncionalidadComun();
}

private void FuncionalidadComun()
{
    //aqui codigo comun
}
```

Si desde dos lugares requieres invocar codigo compartido lo sacas a otra funcion

Comment: En adición, tambien le puede poner al metodo `FuncionalidadComun()` un parametro de tipo `object` por si necesita tomar algo de la firma del evento, ¿No?

Comment: si por supuesto, lo que defini es solo un ejemplo, puede definir los parametros que necesite para pasar datos, pero deberia ser datos simple y devolver un resultado si lo necesita

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios, me fueron de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1):

dentro de la función podrías probar con lo siguiente:

```
ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null,null);
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.